# Unable to let a script populate results using concurrent.futures in a customized manner

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, concurrent.futures

I've created a script in python to scrape the user_name from a site's [landing page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping) and title from it's [inner page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61475708/unable-to-let-a-script-populate-results-using-concurrent-futures-in-a-customized). I'm trying to use `concurrent.futures` library to perform parallel tasks. I know how to use `executor.submit()` within the script below, so I'm not interested to go that way. I would like to go for `executor.map()` which I've already defined (perhaps in the wrong way) within the following script.

I've tried with:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urljoin
import concurrent.futures as futures

URL = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping"
base = "https://stackoverflow.com"

def get_links(s,url):
    res = s.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
    for item in soup.select(".summary"):
        user_name = item.select_one(".user-details > a").get_text(strip=True)
        post_link = urljoin(base,item.select_one(".question-hyperlink").get("href"))
        yield s,user_name,post_link

def fetch(s,name,url):
    res = s.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
    title = soup.select_one("h1[itemprop='name'] > a").text
    return name,title

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with requests.Session() as s:
        with futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
            link_list = [url for url in get_links(s,URL)]
            for result in executor.map(fetch, *link_list):
                print(result)
```

I get the following error when I run the above script as is:

```
TypeError: fetch() takes 3 positional arguments but 50 were given
```

If I run the script modifying this portion `link_list = [url for url in get_links(s,URL)][0]`, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: zip argument #1 must support iteration
```

> How can I successfully execute the above script keeping the existing design intact?

Comment: This `executor.map(lambda p:fetch(*p),link_list)` should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `fetch` takes 3 arguments (s,name,url), you need to to pass 3 *iterables* to `executor.map()`.

When you do this:

```py
executor.map(fetch, *link_list)
```

`link_list` unpacks 49 or so tuples each with 3 elements (the Session object, username, and url). That's not what you want.

What you need to do is first transform `link_list` into 3 separate iterables (one for the Session objects, another for the usernames, and one for the urls). Instead of doing this manually, you can use `zip()` and the unpacking operator twice, like so:

```py
            for result in executor.map(fetch, *zip(*link_list)):
```

Also, when I tested your code, an exception was raised in `get_links`:

```
    user_name = item.select_one(".user-details > a").get_text(strip=True)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'
```

`item.select_one` returned `None`, which obviously doesn't have a `get_text()` method, so I just wrapped that in a try/except block, catching `AttributeError` and continued the loop.

Also note that Requests' Session class isn't thread-safe. **Luckily**, the script returned sane responses when I ran it, but if you need your script to be reliable, you need to address this. A comment in the 2nd link shows how to use one Session instance per thread thanks to thread-local data. See:

- [Document threading contract for Session class](https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/2766)
- [Thread-safety of FutureSession](https://github.com/ross/requests-futures/issues/47)